# Get views referrers in Youtube API V3 or in Youtube Analytics

Tags: youtube-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to get referrers / sources of the views in the new experimental Youtube API v3? We checked these plus the experimental Youtube Analytics API, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

We'd like to get the Referrers report as we can find here in the V2: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight

Thanks,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube Analytic V3 api does not include a way to get referrers or sources.  The available metrics can be viewed on this page. https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets

If you would more metrics to be added please file a feature request here. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)